# Send an email on table update Datatables Editor

Tags: php, email, datatables

I am trying to figure out how to send an email on update.

```
<?php

function my_mail_function(){
    $to = "rma@mysite.net";
    $subject = "RMA Update Completed";

    $values2 = $row['rma_submissions.paid'];

    $message = "
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>RMA Update Complete</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>This is a copy of your RMA Update Request</p>
    <table>
      $values2
    <tr><td>Completed?: <b> Yes </b></td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    ";

    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // More headers
    $headers .= 'From: <noreply@mysite.net>' . "\r\n";


    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}

include( "lib/DataTables.php" );

use
    DataTables\Editor,
    DataTables\Editor\Field,
    DataTables\Editor\Format,
    DataTables\Editor\Mjoin,
    DataTables\Editor\Options,
    DataTables\Editor\Upload,
    DataTables\Editor\Validate,
    DataTables\Editor\ValidateOptions;

    Editor::inst( $db, 'rma_submissions', 'ID' )
        ->fields(
            Field::inst( 'rma_submissions.id' ),
            Field::inst( 'rma_submissions.timestamp' )
                ->validator( Validate::dateFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) )
                ->getFormatter( Format::datetime( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) )
                ->setFormatter( Format::datetime( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) ),
            Field::inst( 'rma_submissions.location' ),
            Field::inst( 'rma_submissions.orig_invoice' ),
            Field::inst( 'rma_submissions.all_accessories' ),
            Field::inst( 'rma_submissions.new_submission' ),
            Field::inst( 'rma_submissions.man_sku' ),
            Field::inst( 'rma_submissions.device_id' ),
            Field::inst( 'rma_submissions.failure_desc' ),
            Field::inst( 'rma_submissions.defective_oob' ),
            Field::inst( 'rma_submissions.original_sales_date' ),
            Field::inst( 'rma_submissions.vendor' ),
            Field::inst( 'rma_submissions.email' ),
            Field::inst( 'rma_submissions.device_man' ),
            Field::inst( 'rma_submissions.district' ),
            Field::inst( 'rma_submissions.rma_number' ),
            Field::inst( 'rma_submissions.paid' ),
            Field::inst( 'rma_submissions.paid_date' ),
            Field::inst( 'rma_reasons.reason_description' ),
        )

        ->leftJoin( 'rma_reasons', 'rma_reasons.reason_code', '=', 'rma_submissions.failure_desc' )

        ->on( 'postEdit', function ( $editor, $id, $values, $row ) {
                my_mail_function();

        } )

        ->process( $_POST )
        ->json();
```

The above does not work correctly.  It sends the email but errors out on frontend and also does not include the variable information.

[image]

If I add just text it sends just fine but when I add any variables it errors out. It has got to be an error on the way im pulling the variable.
Ive tried adding like below.

```
function my_mail_function(){
    $to = "rma@mysite.net";
    $subject = "SKU Update Completed";

    $values2 = $row;

    $message = "
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Sku Update Complete</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       $row['rma_submissions.paid']
    </body>
    </html>
    ";

    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // More headers
    $headers .= 'From: <support@mysite.net>' . "\r\n";


    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
```

What I would like is on an update it sends an email to the listed emails above and inserts data from the table.  Im lost at the moment.

Comment: One thing. You need to enclose your variables representing associative array indexes in double quoted `""` string with curly braces `{}` like `$message="<body>{$row['rma_submissions.paid']}</body>";` Have a look at [this](https://www.tehplayground.com/R8Q6KmrBS9k2dd1j). If I remove `{}`, its a fatal error.

Comment: @UmairKhan If I add the brackets it completely breaks the script for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PHP documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Looking at the example given, the variable expansion for the array shouldn't contain quotes. Please try:

```
$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>Sku Update Complete</title>
</head>
<body>
   $row[rma_submissions.paid]
</body>
</html>
";
```

Generally speaking, because of the complexity of variable expansion I tend towards using concatenation. i.e.

```
$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>Sku Update Complete</title>
</head>
<body>".$row['rma_submissions.paid']."</body>
</html>
";
```

Or I would create a simple template and then use preg replace or such to replace the field place holders with the actual value.